Correct SELinux Policy for MongoDB 7 Enterprise on RHEL 9: .rpm vs .tgz Installation?
I'm following the MongoDB documentation to install MongoDB 7 Enterprise on RHEL 9. When installing the SELinux policy, I used the instructions provided for RHEL 7 and later, as shown below:
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-selinux
cd mongodb-selinux
make
sudo make install

However, I'm encountering SELinux denials related to access for /tmp. But when I follow the instructions for SELinux configuration using the .tgz tarball installation, I don't experience any SELinux denials.
The official MongoDB SELinux instructions mention that the policies provided are for use with RHEL7 and RHEL8. Does this mean that for RHEL 9, the only reliable way to configure SELinux correctly is through the .tgz tarball installation? Or is there an alternative approach that can work with the .rpm installer on RHEL 9?

Can you provide a bit more details, please?
Once, the SELinux policy module is loaded, do you perform a restorecon on the filesystem(s) or directory trees to make sure the binaires have the proper SELinux contexts for the processes to transition as expected in the policy?
Do you implement poly-instantiation on /tmp?
What are the AVC denials you get?
Do you switch the mongod_can_use_kerberos boolean to true?
